# JetBrains Toolbox open project in the same window

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

Path for option:

```
IntelliJ IDEA
  -> Preferences
    -> Appearance & Behavior
      -> System Settings : Project Opening preferences
```

I set option "Open project in the same window" but Toolbox ignores this configuration and uses "Open project in a new window"

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you opening a project? Using `File|Open...`, `File|Open Recent...`, or maybe `File|Open Recent|Manage projects`?

Comment: @konstantin-annikov   [Look at this image](https://imgur.com/a/mkW6tRW) I didn't open with Intellij IDEA. I opened with JetBrain ToolBox

Answer (score 0):

Toolbox always opens the project as a new window of already running IDE instance. There is no feature for checking IDE's Project Opening preferences. 
You can submit a feature request for honoring the option in YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TBX

Answer (score 0):

I created this little AutoIT sript for fix this problem: 

https://github.com/textfx/Auto-Close-IDEA

You're welcome.